# unity dynamic ui save

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, dynamic, save

I am developing with unity is dynamically generated the ui part of my application.
This ui is created by pulling information from the server.
The ui device I created is being recorded.
Whenever there is a change, I pull ui from the server, but if there is no change, I want it to run directly from the device. I need information on this subject.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. What have you tried? Can you please include the relevant source code. 
[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow Alper. In order to achieve this, you need to store the data and see if there are any changes from the previous launch. The easiest way to do this is by using `PlayerPrefs` which is pretty straightforward.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("someName", varName);
```

and similar if you want to save string:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("someAnotherName", stringVarName);
```

Then if you want to access it you can use:

```
 PlayerPrefs.GetInt("someName");
 PlayerPrefs.GetString("someAnotherName");
```

Have in mind that PlayerPrefs is not secure and can be accessed very easy outside of your application. If the information you are going to store have something private I suggest you to use SQLite.